# BiBTex - Multiple bib files --> references do not appear

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I am writing a document and I need to use many bibliography .bib files with it. Even though I include them at the bottom of my document, the bibliography still doesn't load. I am using Overleaf.

Overleaf does not create an error only a warning about the existence of the references. The problem is that when I create the document, it seems to do not load the references and appear as (?,?).

Here is my root file:

[image: Root File]

Here is my minimal code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    
\definecolor{azul}{RGB}{0,0,255}
    
    \newcommand{\enf}[1]{\textcolor{azul}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\autor}{
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        Germán Felipe López Díaz & 201913032\\
    \end{tabular}}
    
    \title{\enf{\textbf{Error}}}
    \author{\textit{\enf{\autor}}}
    \date{\textit{\enf{\today}}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
        \maketitle    
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        
        Texto.
        
        \begin{itemize}[label = \enf{$\star$}]
            \item \textit{\textbf{Inspiración del Estudio \cite{CMKnuthOriginal}.}} XXX.
            \item \textit{\textbf{Axiomatización de los Cuadrados mágicos \cite{CMAndrewsTextoGuia}.}} XXX.
            \item \textit{\textbf{Caracterización de los cuadrados muy mágicos\cite{CMTeoTrivialidad}.}} XXX.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
        \bibliography{-Otros-,
        -1-CuadradosMagicos,
        -2-CaminosDeCaballeroNoCruzantes,
        -3-ProductosFibonacci}
        
    \end{document}
```

Here is how my BibTeX file looks:

[image: BibTeX file]

Comment: So what error are you getting? You can start by reducing the complexity of your document, take out packages that clearly have nothing to do with the issue at hand, remove comments etc. => make a minimal example.

Comment: @Ingmar I rephrase the question because of your comment. thanks by the contribution!

In short, I deleted the comments on the file and make a new review of the packages. If there are still some packages that area not useful, please let me now. The issue is that the referenceas appear as (?.?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "0.3 Propuesta Recargada" your main tex file?  It looks like it's in the folder "0 Propuesta del Proyecto".  I don't think Overleaf handles things well when the main tex file is in a subfolder.

Comment: Yes it is! Let me see...

Comment: I verify it! You are right the problem is my folder. I will need to leave the file outside it while I am editing

Comment: On the other hand, when I leave out the file, there where some missing "," on the BiBTeX file. Thank you!

Comment: What should I do when the issue is solved. Do you know?

Comment: @MathHack Clicking the green checkmark is all you needed to do.  Have a nice day.